# How to automate writer output directory and filename in FME Desktop?

Tags: fme-form

I built a workspace in FME Desktop 2017 for re-projecting DWG files between different coordinate systems and I need to automate the writer output folder and filename of the dwg in FME desktop.

I need to compose automatically the writer output path using: '**reader input path/myfolder/reader filename.dwg**'

Is there anyway to do this in FME Desktop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, this is quite simple - less than five minutes, which I know because I created a movie demonstrating it:

https://www.screencast.com/t/zdnVYkVGnJEv

To give the steps in more detail here...

1) The source filename information comes from the source dataset parameter (say SourceDataset_ACAD) in the Navigator window

2) Put down a FileNamePartExtractor transformer to break down that source dataset parameter into its component parts, eg dirpath and filename

3) For MyFolder (which I assume the user gets to enter) create a new published/user parameter that lets the user enter a filename.

4) Go to the Navigator window and look for Dataset Fanout for the ACAD output. Turn it on and set the fanout expression to be:

```
@Value(dirpath)\$(MyFolder)\@Value(filename)
```

5. Run the translation. Enter a MyFolder value. If the data was originally C:\FMEData2016\Data\Transportation\Roads.dwg, and MyFolder is called "Mark", then the output will be C:\FMEData2016\Data\Transportation\Mark\Roads.dwg

Another thing you could do (for example) is use the TimeStamper transformer to create a timestamp and incorporate that into the file/path name of the output. That way each output is timestamped in its name. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: what about going one level up from source path? From C:\FMEData2016\Data\Transportation\Roads.dwg to C:\FMEData2016\Data\Roads.dwg

Comment: To go up one path would need a level stripping off the existing path. In the Fanout editor you'd need to use a regular expression or other string function to search for - and strip off - the last part surrounded by \ characters. For example this: @ReplaceRegEx(@Value(_dirpath),[^\\]+\\?$,"")\@Value(_filename) would just move the file up a level. If you still wanted the MyFolder part, try this: @ReplaceRegEx(@Value(_dirpath),[^\\]+\\?$,"")\@Value(_filename) - which will strip the last level and replace it with the MyFolder automatically.

Comment: btw - the regex part I got from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259471/regex-remove-last-folder-from-path - if you have a S/O account, why not go vote it up as a thank you!

Comment: OK, that second regex should be: @ReplaceRegEx(@Value(_dirpath),[^\]+\\?$,$(MyFolder))\@Value(_fil‌​ename)

Comment: What about shape file, it seems to not work with shape files, i can't fanout shape file with the same expression

Comment: Shapefiles are a little different. They are based on a folder, not a specific filename. So just use @Value(dirpath)\$(MyFolder)\ in the dataset fanout. In the writer feature type (the brown object on the canvas) open its properties and set the layer name to @Value(filename) - then all should work as with other formats.

Comment: i get the error "MULTI_WRITER: No dataset was specified for MULTI_WRITER_DATASET or SHAPEFILE_2_DATASET or SHAPEFILE_DATASET
MULTI_WRITER: No dataset was specified for MULTI_WRITER_DATASET or SHAPEFILE_2_DATASET or SHAPEFILE_DATASET
Destination Feature Type Routing Correlator (RoutingFactory): MULTI_WRITER: No dataset was specified for MULTI_WRITER_DATASET or SHAPEFILE_2_DATASET or SHAPEFILE_DATASET
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=                                                                                        I want to add multiple shape files using folder selection

Comment: i also get this error if i select more then one shape file:Shapefile writer: Unable to create directory 'V:\!!!!!Pyje Kullota 2019\5 - DORZIME P2\DIVJAKE +\""V:\!!!!!Pyje Kullota 2019\5 - DORZIME P2\DIVJAKE +\3503\SHP\LU3503SP_P.shp" "V:\!!!!!Pyje Kullota 2019\5 - DORZIME P2\DIVJAKE +\2289\SHP\KRGJSH2'. Ensure you have write permissions to the parent folder, the network location is reachable, or that the disk is not full
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
... Last line repeated 3 times ...

Comment: @MarkIreland this works great even with Tab files but I can't figure out how to get it to work on a folder of files and not just one? I tried it using FileCopyWriter but no luck. Basically I need it to take files from X:\library\somefolder to Y:\NewLibrary\somefolder and as with this question re project the files in the process.

Comment: @GeorgeC It should work, so it's hard to determine why it doesn't. Is it just working on one file, no matter how many you pick? If so, is it actually reading all of the source data or not? That might need a Merge Filter setting to allow all data to pass. Check the log for warnings about that. In fact, check the log file for any warnings or errors anyway. Maybe you could post this as a new question, so that you can include your log and screenshots of the workspace, and so we have more space to discuss? Plus there's more chance others will see it and have a solution.