# How to set output directory in Writer dynamically?

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer, fme-flow, fme-flow-hosted

I am trying to export feature set into CSV using writer. But when I tried to set variable as directory path for dataset it throw me error checkout picture 1. When I set manually folder path it work well. I would like to set path variable from script params to save CSV output to that path. Any information how to set. I am creating this writer newly. When I checked existing writer it show like picture 2.

Picture 1 :

[image]

Picture 2 :
[image]

Error log after trying as per Picture 1.

```
Undefined macro `OUTPUT_DIR_SCRIPTED' dereferenced in file `/tmp/FME_1622633462491_53461'
Program Terminating

Translation FAILED.
```

Unfortunately this answer video not working for me [How to automate writer output directory and filename in FME Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245057/how-to-automate-writer-output-directory-and-filename-in-fme-desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer immediately posting question by comparing existing writer setting. I am posting answer to help others.

Steps :

1. Create writer by providing any sample path for dataset.
   [image]
2. Once writer got created right click on it and open edit "Path you provided [CSV] " some text will be there like shown in below picture.
   [image]
3. After opening this setting will look like below picture
   [image]
4. Click on arrow and select open text editor
   [image]
5. Select variable which you need to mapped
   [image]
6. Then after selection save settings
   [image]
7. Then you are done. see below final changes.

[image]